# R: Using the R-bloomberg package to get market depth

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am looking for a way to find market depth for a stock using the R-Bloomberg (Rbbg) package. 
As an example, if I enter "MSM" (a ticker) I would like to see the top, say, 5 bids and asks for MSM.

Would anyone be able to help me?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BEST_ASKI` and `BEST_BIDI` fields (where `I` can be 1 to 9), which update in real time. For example: `BEST_ASK1` gives you the best offer, `BEST_ASK2` the second best offer etc.

You obviously need to have the appropriate subscriptions to access that data through the API.

Comment: I just tried it with the following in excel : =BDP(("MSM SJ EQUITY"),"BEST_BID1"), but it keeps returning "#N/A N/A", even though my other feeds are working. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Mike It works for me (with a different ticker - I don't have market depth in South Africa) - maybe that specific ticker does not provide market depth. You can check on `BQ <Go>` if you see anything.

Comment: oh ok. Yeah I've tried it for a few, and it isn't giving me an "invalid field" error, so maybe you're correct and the function isn't available for those stocks. Thanks again for your help!