# Not able to get bloomberg market depth data using Rbbg or Rblpapi package

Tags: r, streaming, bloomberg

I have a Bloomberg subscription to view market depth data for (among others) the bund future, RXM6 Comdty. I want to download this data real-time using R.

However, using the bdp function from either the Rbbg package or the Rblpapi package, the BEST_BID2, ..., BEST_BID10 fields report an NA (same for BEST_ASK).

This is supposed to work according to [R: Using the R-bloomberg package to get market depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231362/r-using-the-r-bloomberg-package-to-get-market-depth). Furthermore, using the excel-Bloomberg tool, I am able to download this data in excel.

Also, other fields such as "BID" or "PX_LAST" do report correct numbers using Rbbg or Rblpapi. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

These fields are only accessible through subscriptions, not reference data request.

I have never used Rblpapi but, looking at [the reference manual](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Rblpapi/index.html), I suspect that this should work:

```
subscribe(securities=c("RXM6 Comdty"),
          fields=c("BEST_BID2", "BEST_BID3"),
          fun=function(x) print(str(x$data)))
```